# I cannot run npm install - ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, npm

I have recently just cloned my project on to a fresh computer from Github. I deleted my node modules and ran npm install and I was presented with:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-firebase/auth@14.2.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-firebase/app@13.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/app@"^13.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"13.0.1" from @react-native-firebase/storage@13.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/storage@"^13.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-native-firebase/app@"14.2.1" from @react-native-firebase/auth@14.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/auth@"^14.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-native-firebase/app@14.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"14.2.1" from @react-native-firebase/auth@14.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/auth@"^14.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/jacksaunders/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacksaunders/.npm/_logs/2022-06-18T18_48_11_817Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried downgrading the packages, but I don't think I'm doing it right because it is not working. I have tried ***npm audit fix*** but that didn't work for me either and I am presented with the same error as above.

If anyone can help me get back up and running that would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: What version of firebase are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be a directory issue. When cloning projects, you may have put your project folder inside a new folder you created. For example, C:/Users/myApp/myApp

Double check that your terminal you are running commands from is in the correct directory. This is a simple mistake I have made many times, causing that exact error.

If that is not the case, then I would freshly reinstall Firebase on this project. Check the log and see if all of the errors are firebase related from your code sample. Completely uninstalling firebase after npm install and installing the package separately can fix the issue.

Comment: I am running a terminal in my IDE (WebStorm) so I am in the correct directory/level. That's also another problem, I can't install or uninstall any packages either. I have tried deleting the project and cloning it again into the documents folder on my mac. No luck, no idea what's causing the issue.

Comment: I do not use webstorm often but even in visual studio code I have clicked “Terminal -> New Terminal” and it was the incorrect directory.

Comment: “Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps“ have you tried either of these commands to try and resolve the firebase issue?

Comment: Hi @Corey, I'm not what the issue was in the end. But, it is fixed. I started by deleting my node modules > npm install --legacy-peer-deps (as you suggested) > pod install > pod repo update. Then I fell into a rabbit hole after that doing npm audit fix etc... Took me all day! But, you put me on the right track! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wish I was able to give you more info man, but super glad you were able to fix it!